# Can't draw with glDrawTexfOES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I can't draw a texture with `glDrawTextOES` in my Android app. I've tried the SpriteMethodTest code and I can't get it to work...

However, here's the code:

Code for cropping when loading texture:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        int[] mCropWorkspace = new int[4];
        mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
        mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
        mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
        mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();

        bitmap.recycle();

        ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);
```

Code for drawing:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, 0.0f, width, height);
```

Any ideas? I got it to work with Vertex Arrays and Vertex Buffer Objects, but not with this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have properly height and width for your image, e.g: `512x512` or `512x1024` so it fills a quad/rectangle, specified by your `GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES`.